# Insert data into empty cells in ascending order

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, window-functions, generate-series

I have a Postgres table with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
id integer,
name text,
date date,
time time without tz
);

CREATE TABLE tb2 (
id integer,
name text,
date date
);
```

I need to generate a 3rd table `tb3` that will have column `time_now` with increment steps by 10 minutes. If `tb1.time` is not the same as `tb3.time_now` then `b2.name` is filled in. If `tb1.time` equals (or close by `time_now`) it is inserted into `tb3`.
Example:

tb1

```
1, xxxx, 2014-10-01, 08:20:00
2, yyyy, 2014-10-01, 08:40:00
```

tb2

```
1, zzzz, 2014-10-01
2, vvvv, 2014-10-01
3, eeee, 2014-10-01
```

3rd table should look like:

```
1, 08:00:00,zzzz -----> from tb2
2, 08:10:00,vvvv -----> from tb2
3, 08:20:00,xxxx -----> from tb1
4, 08:30:00,eeee -----> from tb2
5, 08:40:00,yyyy -----> from tb1
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.time::text, COALESCE(t.name, t2.name) AS name
FROM  (
   SELECT g.id, g.time, t1.name
        , CASE WHEN t1.name IS NULL THEN
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.name ORDER BY g.id)
          END AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT g AS id, '08:00'::time + '10 min'::interval * (g-1) AS time
      FROM   generate_series (1,6) g
      ) g
   LEFT JOIN tb1 t1 USING (time)
   ) t
LEFT   JOIN tb2 t2 ON t2.id = t.rn
ORDER  BY t.id;
```

1. First build a table of desired times with `generate_series()`. From 8:00 to 8:50 in my example.
2. Join to tb1 on `time`. Attach ascending numbers to empty slots with `row_number()` (rn).
3. Join `tb2` to the remaining empty slots in ascending order.
4. Use COALESCE to pick names from `tb1` and `tb2`.

Be wary about off-by-1 errors.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8486b/7)

Aside: I would use *none* of those column names. `id` and `name` are not descriptive - never use those, be more specific. `date` and `time` are basic type names.

Comment: Thx for help, one other question, now if t1.time is not equal to tb1.time, entry will not be shown. Can this query be modified in a way to cover that case as well?

Comment: One other question if you can explain to me, what is t1?

Comment: @jack_oneal: `t1` is a table alias for tb1, declared in the FROM list here: `LEFT JOIN tb1 t1`, which is short for `LEFT JOIN tb1 AS t1`. For your other question, I suggest you start a new question, where you define "not equal" more closely. You can always reference this question for context.